# Auto populate input based on file name with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

I am playing around with AngularJS and have not been able to solve this problem. I have a view  that has a form to upload a file to a node server. So far I have manage to do this using some directives and a service. I allow the user to send a custom name to the POST data if they desire. What I wan to accomplish is that when the user selects a file the `filename` models auto populates.

My view looks like:

```
<div>
    <input file-model="phpFile" type="file">
    <input name="filename" type="text" ng-model="filename">
    <button ng-click="send()">send</button>
</div>
```

`file-model` is my directive that allows the file to be assigned to a scope.

```
myApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse.(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;
            element.bind('change', function() {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        } 
}]);
```

The service:

```
myApp.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function($http){
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl, optionals) {
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);
        for (var key in file) {
            fd.append(key, file[key]);
        }
        for(var i = 0; i < optionals.length; i++){
            fd.append(optionals[i].name, optionals[i].data);
        }
    });
}]);
```

Here as you can see I pass the file, append its properties, and append any optional properties.

In the controller is where I am having the troubles. I have tried `$watch` and using the `file-model` but I get the same error either way.

```
myApp.controller('AddCtrl', function($scope, $location, PEberry, fileUpload){
    //$scope.$watch(function() {
    //    return $scope.phpFile;
    //},function(newValue, oldValue) {
    //    $scope.filename = $scope.phpFile.name;
    //}, true);
    // if ($scope.phpFiles) {
    //     $scope.filename = $scope.phpFiles.name;
    // }
    $scope.send = function() {
        var uploadUrl = "/files";
        var file = $scope.phpFile;
        //var opts = [{ name: "uname", data: file.name }]

        fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
    };
});
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on a project.  I solved it by using this [library](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload).

My input in my HTML file was this:

```
<input type="file" ng-file-select="onImageFileSelect($files, $event);" accept="image/*" >
```

In my controller, I had a function (some parts of that function were redacted):

```
$scope.onImageFileSelect = function($files, event) {
    $scope.userInfo.image.file = $files[0];
}
```

That set up the scope so that in my HTML file I could print the file name using:

```
<div>{{userInfo.image.file.name}}</div>
```

Since the user was uploading a profile image for their account, I wanted to give them the ability to automatically see a thumbnail.  For that I used another library called fileReader that wraps the Javascript file reader function.